# How disable QuickMemo+ in a LG G5?

Tags: lg, lg-g5

In my LG G5 is appearing cosntantly this error message:

> Unfortunately, QuickMemo+ has stopped.

These message appears several times per day and I'm not using that app: QuickMemo+ and it can't be disabled in the Configuration > Apps > QuickMemo+. The Disable button appears disabled.

Any idea how to disable this app?

Thanks

Comment: You could try doing that via [ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info), using `adb shell "pm hide <package_name>"`. Of course, first you'd have to figure the package name of QuickMemo; `adb shell "pm list packages"` might help you with that.

Comment: I get notifications "quickmemo+ permission requested" but I cannot disable the app on my LG G7 ThinQ either. The App Notifications options only have "Icon Badge" and we cannot prevent notifications. I suppose we are stuck with these annoying notifications.